# Issue with matching enum with options

Tags: rust, match

I have this parser which used to parse mail and i need to parse the from details from i use rust mail_parser crate. there the parsed input from details are extracted using `from` method the `from` method returns an enum called `HeaderValue` [link](https://docs.rs/mail-parser/0.8.2/mail_parser/enum.HeaderValue.html)

what i can't understand is if i need to get the `Address(Addr<'x>)` the Address is an option which contains this option

```
   pub struct Addr<'x> {
    pub name: Option<Cow<'x, str>>,
    pub address: Option<Cow<'x, str>>,
}
```

what i'm getting issue is can't make the match to get the data from the `Address(Addr<'x>)` and extract the option. if i need to get the `name` and `address` fields to struct how can i make the `match` statement?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not any hard, just the standard syntax. What errors did you face exactly?

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

pub struct Addr<'x> {
    pub name: Option<Cow<'x, str>>,
    pub address: Option<Cow<'x, str>>,
}

pub enum HeaderValue<'x> {
    Address(Addr<'x>),
    AddressList(Vec<Addr<'x>>),
    Empty,
}

fn main() {
    let value = HeaderValue::Address(Addr{name: Some("somename".into()), address: None});
    match value {
        HeaderValue::Address(Addr{name, address}) => println!("Parsed name={:?} address={:?}", name, address),
        _ => println!("Couldn't match"),
    }
}
```

Prints

> Parsed name=Some("somename") address=None

Or for more control over matching different combinations:

```
match value {
        HeaderValue::Address(Addr{name:Some(name), address:Some(address)}) => println!("Parsed both name={:?} address={:?}", name, address),
        HeaderValue::Address(Addr{address:Some(address), ..}) => println!("Parsed only address={:?}", address),
        HeaderValue::Address(Addr{name:Some(name), ..}) => println!("Parsed only name={:?}", name),
        HeaderValue::Address(Addr{..}) => println!("Parsed empty"),
        _ => println!("Couldn't match"),
}
```

Prints

> Parsed only name="somename"

### Answer to the comment:

I don't think you can do that with a single `match` statement, but you can do multiple `if let` statements like so

```
let value = HeaderValue::Address(Addr{name: Some("somename".into()), address: None});
if let HeaderValue::Address(Addr{address:Some(address), ..}) = &value {
    println!("Parsed address={:?}", address);
}
if let HeaderValue::Address(Addr{name:Some(name), ..}) = &value {
    println!("Parsed name={:?}", name);
}
```

Prints:

> Parsed name="somename"

Comment: thank you. what if i need to get parse the name and address differently so in rust the match statement return the first matched value and ignore others. from single match statement how can i do that?

Comment: @devMe see the answer, I made an edit to address your question